# How to make waterfall chart be specific to date widget range

Tags: einstein-analytics

Einstein Analytics Sales App has a really great waterfall chart:

[image: waterfall chart]

That chart is powered by a sizable pigql query statement (8kb in size) using to 10 different date lookups from the static step "step_time".

[image]

I want this to be calculated based on a date range widget so I can look at this chart from "Sept 1 to Sept 14" or do any random dates I need.  Unfortunately, it looks like I would either be doing a LOT of date math in the pigql (and adding a log of logic there) or I would need to add a LOT of different options to the step_time step.

Except, maybe consolidating the CloseDate filter to its own widget/step.